# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/app/main.js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular, razor

I have setup for Angular JS 2.x project in Visual Studio 2015 environment. I have followed the steps in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

It works fine if I set Start up file as Index.html. 
But, As I am using asp.net MVC project I wanted to use \Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml as master page and \Views\Home\Index.cshtml as original Angular JS page.

So _Layout.cshtml will have @RenderBody(); to render Index.cshtml file which will have angular 2.x selector element <my-app>Loading...</my-app>.

While running the application I am getting following error which is related to referring the app/main.js file.

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    http://localhost/app/main.js**

I have not changed any path reference. Everything is as per instructions given above link except adding the following element in _Layout.cshtml. which helps me to find the referenced files from the root directory.

**<base href="./">**

Here is the list of files I am using for my project.

```html
_Layout.cshtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- base href is must to specify location of app folder -->
    <base href="./"> 

    <title>Angular JS 2 </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="~/systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    @RenderBody();
   
</body>
</html>
```

```html
index.cshtml
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

```html
package.json
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

```js
systemjs.config.js
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: 'main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

```js
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

```js
main.ts
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

```js
app.module.ts
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId:module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>{{name}}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
    name = "Ultimate";
    

}
```

Comment: Why are you using basehref `./`? Try with `/`